# QueryList changes subscribe does not work

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

I have a `QueryList` in a component. I am adding dynamically other components, that will be present in the `QueryList`, but if I subscribe to the `changes` of the `QueryList`, nothing happens. I thought it is because I subscribed in `ngAfterViewInit`, but the `QueryList` is `undefined` yet in `ngOnInit`.

[Here I have the plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/D31pOGsnR9hMDHaE5OZ8?p=preview).

**code:**

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {

    @ViewChildren(ControlFactoryDirective) factories:
        QueryList<ControlFactoryDirective>
    
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.factories.changes.subscribe(() => {
        console.log('changed')
      })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The thing is, the list that comes to your `factories` property is already pre-populated. So you just don't have a chance to subscribe to its changes *before* it's populated for the first time. But all changes that happen later are coming through to your subscriber, of course.

Here is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/3RiUGGQiMpDIyU568QXd) with your example updated - notice that factories now has a setter which proves that it's prepopulated (you normally don't need it in a real app, that's for finding out only what value comes from the framework)

I think it's a totally valid behavior. So in `ngAfterViewInit`, loop over values in the QueryList and do the same thing you are about to do in the subscriber:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.processChildren(); // first call to processChildren

  this.factories.changes.subscribe(_ => 
      this.processChildren() // subsequent calls to processChildren
  );
}

private processChildren(): void {
  console.log('Processing children. Their count:', this.factories.toArray().length)
}
```

Comment: Note that `changes` will no longer be issued if you override the `notifyOnChanges` method. Unless you manually issue a value inside the overriden `notifyOnChanges` method I guess (I did not test that assumption)

Answer (score 7):

You can also add `startWith(undefined)` like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.factories.changes.pipe(startWith(undefined)).subscribe(() => 
  {
     console.log('changed')
  })
}
```

This will trigger the subscription handler immediately.

Comment: `startWith(undefined)` is deprecated now, you should use `startWith([undefined])`.

Comment: @yktoo oh no I'm going to have to fix it in a lot of places. I wish Angular would just give me the value + changes in a single observable. Applies to FormGroup.changes too.

Comment: `startWith([undefined])` saved my day after two hours of searching.

Answer (score 3):

After you make a change to the objects in query list you should call query list to notify on changes.

```
update() {
  this.factories.forEach(factory => {
    console.log(factory.componentRef.instance.model.data = "alma")
  //  factory.()
  this.factories.notifyOnChanges();
  })
}
```

Comment: Then I have to add the `notifyOnChanges` in `ControlFactoryDirective`'s `create`, but I cannot add there ... I want to detect the changes when adding the components

Answer (score 1):

```
export class AppComponent {
    factoryList : any = [{ id: 1,name: "abc", detail: "abc abc abc"}];

    @ViewChildren(ControlFactoryDirective) factoryDirective:
        QueryList<ControlFactoryDirective>
    
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.factoryDirective.changes.subscribe(() => {
        console.log('changed')
      })
    }
    addNewfactory(){
     this.factoryList .push({ id: 11,name: "xyz", detail: "xyz xyz xyz"});
    }
}

I assume that ControlFactoryDirective is used in html like below. Number of the components and used Factory objects depends on the factoryList size. When button is clicked a new Factory object will be added to the factoryList. factoryList size is changed, new ControlFactoryDirective component is added/displayed, also subscribe method will be called. 

<button (click)="addNewfactory()">Add</button>

<controlfactorydirective *ngFor='let factory of factoryList'
  [factory]="factory">
</controlfactorydirective >
```